# Merging dictionaries with duplicates in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a code that will merge 3 difference dictionaries (two other dictionaries into the first main dictionary.) when there are duplicate keys while retaining the values. 
I am currently stuck at the point where I find the duplicates and I have trouble adding them to newDict or d1. Can anyone help me so that each duplicate becomes somekind of object where I can pass it to be added to the new dictionary containing all other keys? Thank you.

```
d1 = {'Norton': '408-771-7231', 'Edward': '415-669-7234', 'Julia':'510-669-7723'}
# Phone number information / "newDict"
d2 = {'Norton': '12345 El Monte Road', 'James': '4236 Capitol Expressway', 'Mary': '6345 Mia Circle'}
# Address information
d3 = {'Norton': 'Male', 'James': 'Male', 'John': 'Male', 'Elizabeth': 'Female'}
# Gender Information
newDict = d1
# d1 will act as the main dictionary and retain all of it's entries and receive entries.

newDictKeys=newDict.keys()
d1Keys=d1.keys()
d2Keys=d2.keys()
d3Keys=d3.keys()

allKeys = [d2Keys, d3Keys]  # Left out d1Keys since it will retain it's entries.
print('Printing original dictionary entries...','\n','d1 =', d1, '\n', 'd2 =', d2, '\n', 'd3 =', d3, '\n')

print('Cross referencing keys from d1 with d2Keys and d3Keys...')

tempList = []

def addToDictForSameKey(comboDictionary, addOnDictionary, key):
    return None


for keysOfDictX in allKeys:
    for keyX in keysOfDictX:
        print('\nChecking key:', keyX)

        for keyY in newDict:
            print('With this key in newDict:', keyY)

            if keyX == keyY:  # check for identical keys
                addToDictForSameKey(newDict, d2, keyX)
                print('Found Duplicate', keyX, 'with', keyY, 'in', keysOfDictX)
                print('adding to newDict')
                break
            else:

                continue

print('\n', newDict)
```

Output:

```
Printing original dictionary entries... 
 d1 = {'Norton': '408-771-7231', 'Edward': '415-669-7234', 'Julia': '510-669-7723'} 
 d2 = {'Norton': '12345 El Monte Road', 'James': '4236 Capitol Expressway', 'Mary': '6345 Mia Circle'} 
 d3 = {'Norton': 'Male', 'James': 'Male', 'John': 'Male', 'Elizabeth': 'Female'} 

Cross referencing keys from d1 with d2Keys and d3Keys...

Checking key: Norton
With this key in newDict: Norton
Found Duplicate Norton with Norton in dict_keys(['Norton', 'James', 'Mary'])
adding to newDict

Checking key: James
With this key in newDict: Norton
With this key in newDict: Edward
With this key in newDict: Julia

Checking key: Mary
With this key in newDict: Norton
With this key in newDict: Edward
With this key in newDict: Julia

Checking key: Norton
With this key in newDict: Norton
Found Duplicate Norton with Norton in dict_keys(['Norton', 'James', 'John', 'Elizabeth'])
adding to newDict

Checking key: James
With this key in newDict: Norton
With this key in newDict: Edward
With this key in newDict: Julia

Checking key: John
With this key in newDict: Norton
With this key in newDict: Edward
With this key in newDict: Julia

Checking key: Elizabeth
With this key in newDict: Norton
With this key in newDict: Edward
With this key in newDict: Julia

 {'Norton': '408-771-7231', 'Edward': '415-669-7234', 'Julia': '510-669-7723'}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
   {['Norton': '408-771-7231', '12345 El Monte Road', 'Male'] ['Edward': '415-669-7234'] ['Julia': '510-669-7723'] 
['James': '4325 Capitol Expressway', 'Male'] ['Mary': '6345 Mia Circle'] ['John': 'Male'] ['Elizabeth':'Female']}
```

Basically everything (or at least only the duplicate entries) be in a list that is inside of the dictionary in a single print statement.

Comment: What would you like the output to look like? Give an example with *Norton*

Comment: updated desired output

Answer (score 0):

If you are likely to have duplicates then it would probably better to make them all `list`s of attributes so you don't have to do conditionals on access.

However, if you want the conditional list on duplication then just construct the `list` on duplication:

```
def addToDictForSameKey(comboDictionary, addOnDictionary, key):
    try:  # Already a list
        comboDictionary[key].append(addOnDictionary[key])
    except AttributeError:
        comboDictionary[key] = [comboDictionary[key], addOnDictionary[key]]

for d in (d2, d3):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k in d1:
             addToDictForSameKey(d1, d, k):
```

Would create a super dict of all three dicts with duplicate keys turning into `list`s of attributes.

Comment: It's for a beginners python class so I have to follow this method of using loops and dictionaries.

Comment: The solution you gave me outputs multiple lines of the dictionary building itself, although the last line in the output is the answer that I am looking for. How do I build upon my code I've already written? I think part of the assignment was not to take shortcuts, even though it seems kind of tedious.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was this:

```
d0 = {}

for key in set(d1.keys() + d2.keys() + d3.keys()):
    try:
        d0.setdefault(key,[]).append(d1[key])
    except KeyError:
        pass

    try:
        d0.setdefault(key,[]).append(d2[key])
    except KeyError:
        pass

    try:
        d0.setdefault(key,[]).append(d3[key])
    except KeyError:
        pass

print (d0)
```